# Can any subset of $x$ be moved out of $x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x$ be a set and let $y\subset x$. Does there exist a set $z$ such that:

(1) $z\cap x=\emptyset$ and

(2) there exists a bijection $y \to z$ ?

It is quite intuitive that the answer should be yes. My first attempt was to take a set $x'\notin x$ and to consider $z=y\times \{ x'\}$. But I am unable to show $z\cap x=\emptyset$. I could imagine a proof with the axiom of choice, but I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Try $z = y\times \{x\}$. Then $z\cap x = \varnothing$ by the axiom of foundation.

Comment: Dear @DanielFischer: could you elaborate ?

Comment: $z = y\times \{x\} = \{ \{a, \{a,x\}\} : a \in y\}$. Supposing we had $z\cap x \neq\varnothing$, we'd have $x \in \{a,x\} \in \{a,\{a,x\}\} \in x$ for some $a \in y$, which is forbidden by foundation (that's NBG, I don't know how the equivalent is called and formulated in ZF).

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks ! If you put this comment into an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: @DanielFischer You should feel free to post your comment as an answer; I didn't intend to deprive you of that opportunity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choosing $z = y\times \{x\} = \bigl\{ \{\{a\},\{a,x\}\} : a \in y\bigr\}$ works, since the axiom of foundation guarantees that $z \cap x = \varnothing$ then. For otherwise, there'd be an $a\in y$ with

$$x \in \{a,x\} \in \{\{a\},\{a,x\}\} \in x.$$

Comment: Should there be brackets around your $a$'s?  Or are you using a definition other than Kuratowski's?

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs. Could be that that includes more $\{\}$s. But I think this one works too.

Comment: It's not clear to me that it has the desired property that $(a,b) = (c,d) \implies a = c \wedge b = d$.  If $a$ itself is a pair, then it seems like it might be hard to figure out the first and second coordinates of $\{a,\{a,x\}\}$.

Comment: Since $a \in \{a,x\}$, figuring out the first component shouldn't be a problem. But if I'm overlooking something, just replacing with a working definition of ordered pairs would do it. I'm just hunting for my set theory book to look up Kuratowski's.

Comment: I see.  But it's nice to have a definition of ordered pair that works without assuming foundation. Kuratowski's definition, $(a,x) = \{\{a\},\{a,x\}\}$, has this property.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Yes, that's nicer.

Comment: @TrevorWilson However here's little use in avoiding foundation for a definition of all-purpose ordered pair when we ultimately need foundation to show $z\cap x=\emptyset$. In fact, we could use an ad hoc construction such as $z=\{\,\{a,x\}\mid a\in x\,\}$ as - again on the basis of foundation - this is disjoint to and in bijection with $x$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I do think it is useful (in general, rather than in the context of this question) to have a definition of ordered pair that can be proved to have the desired property without using foundation.  Also, according to bof we don't need foundation for this question anyway.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit: simplified version**

The Axiom of Foundation is not needed.

**Theorem.** Given a set $X$ we can find a set $Y$, disjoint from $X$, and a bijection from $X$ to $Y$.

**Proof.** Let $$T=\{(S,x):(S,x)\in X\wedge(S,x)\notin S\}$$and let$$Y=\{(T,x):x\in X\}.$$Of course $x\mapsto (T,x)$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$. Assume for a contradiction that $X\cap Y\ne\emptyset$. This means that there is an element $x\in X$ such that $(T,x)\in X$. Now, according to the definition of $T$,$$(T,x)\in T\Leftrightarrow(T,x)\in X\wedge(T,x)\notin T.$$Since $(T,x)\in X$ by assumption, we arrive at the contradiction$$(T,x)\in T\Leftrightarrow(T,x)\notin T.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the contradiction?  It seems like we would need $T \subset X$ in order to get the Russell-like contradiction $(T,x) \in T \iff (T,x) \notin T$, because of the condition $S \subset X$ in the definition of $T$.

Comment: It still seems like you only get $(T,x) \in T \iff T \subset X \wedge (T,x) \notin T$.  So if $T \not\subset X$ then there is no contradiction.

Comment: @TrevorWilson $T\subseteq X$. I was still parsing the set consrtructor, which one might rewrite matching the axiom of comprehension: $T=\{\,t\in X\mid \exists S, x\colon t=(S,x), S\subseteq X, t\notin S\,\}$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I just reordered the conditions and introduced $t$ as variable for $(S,x)$

Comment: @TrevorWilson $T:=\{(S,x):\dots,(S,x)\in X,\dots\}\subseteq X$

Comment: @bof Yes, somehow although I saw how the condition $(S,x) \in X$ was needed for part of the argument, I forgot about it when thinking about the other part.  Anyway, I am satisfied now; thanks for the explanation.

Comment: So axioms used are just Extensionality, Pairing (hidden in $(,)$), Comprehension (for $T$), Replacement (for $Y$), I guess? Nice.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $Y\subseteq P(X)\times X$ so I guess Powerset is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment that I deleted.  You don't need the power set axiom to get $Y$ from $X$ and $T$, just replacement applied to the class function $x \mapsto (T,x)$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson You don't need power set, **just** replacement? I don't know much about axiomatic set theory, but I thought the power set axiom was more basic than replacement. I mean, the power set axiom was one of the original Zermelo axioms, wasn't it? And replacement was added later?

Comment: Yes, that is the historical order, although I'm not sure I would agree that it is conceptually more basic. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that it isn't the case that _both_ power set and replacement are needed, which is what I took your comment to mean.  But perhaps you were instead saying that we could _replace_ "replacement" with "power set" in Hagen von Eitzen's list and it would still be valid, in which case I agree.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't clear, but I meant to point out that you didn't need anything as strong as replacement, the power set axiom is enough. Hmm. I guess Powerset and Replacement are both "large cardinal axioms", at the low end of the scale? Are they a counterexample to the alleged linear ordering of large cardinal axioms? But you can do a lot of math without replacement, and I don't think you can get very far without power sets. For us non-set-theoreticians, $P(\mathbb N)$ and $P(\mathbb R)$ come up a lot more often than $\aleph_{\omega}$. That's why I think of power set as being more basic.

Comment: That's a good question regarding the linear ordering of large cardinal axioms. Neither of the natural models for ZF - replacement and ZF - powerset (namely $V_{\omega+\omega}$ and $H_{\omega_1}$) contains the other, so the answer isn't clear to me.  I think of "power set + replacement" as being a large cardinal axiom, whereas neither on its own is very strong, and for a lot of basic stuff (like Cartesian products) one or the other will suffice.  I suppose that power set is more useful for ordinary mathematics, although many things can be rephrased to avoid it.

Comment: Very nice proof, thanks ! When it will be possible, I will offer a bounty.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Come to think of it, I wonder why I put that condition $S\subseteq X$ in the definition of $T$. I don't see a reason for it, so I've taken it out. If there **was** a reason for it, which I'm not seeing, I hope someone will tell me about it. I think it looks a lot more natural now.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I hope the simplified version is I just posted is OK. By the way, where is Extensionality used? (I really only know naive set theory, I'm not in the habit of paying attention to the "little" axioms.)

Comment: @Cantlog Glad you like the proof. I hope the simplified version I just posted is OK. I couldn't recall why I put the condition "$S\subseteq X$" in the definition of $T$--it must have seemed like a good idea at the time but I don't see it now--so I edited it out.

Comment: It is fine with me.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Daniel Fischer's comment, we can prove this using the axiom of foundation, or more easily (in my opinion) using the consequence that every set has an ordinal rank.

Take your set $x'$ to be any set with rank at least that of $x$, say $x' = x$ itself.  Then every element of $y \times \{x'\}$ will have rank greater than that of $x$ because the rank of an ordered pair is greater than the ranks of its components.  On the other hand, every element of $x$ has rank less than that of $x$.  Therefore $x \cap (y \times \{x'\}) = \emptyset$.